# Spark streaming not remembering previous state

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I wrote spark streaming program with stateful transformation.
It seems like my spark streaming application is doing computation correctly with check pointing.
But if i terminate my program and if i start it again, it's not reading the previous checkpointing data and staring from the beginning. Is it the expected behaviour?

Do i need to change anything in my program so that it will remember the previous data and start computation from there?

Thanks in advance.

For reference my program:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseStream")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
    val inputStream = ssc.socketTextStream(<hostname>, 9999)
    ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://<hostname1>:8020/user/spark/checkpoints_dir")
    inputStream.print(1)
    val parsedStream = inputStream
      .map(line => {
        val splitLines = line.split(",")
        (splitLines(1), splitLines.slice(2, splitLines.length).map((_.trim.toLong)))
      })
    import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV}
    import scala.util.Try

    val state: DStream[(String, Array[Long])] = parsedStream.updateStateByKey(
      (current: Seq[Array[Long]], prev: Option[Array[Long]]) =>  {
        prev.map(_ +: current).orElse(Some(current))
          .flatMap(as => Try(as.map(BDV(_)).reduce(_ + _).toArray).toOption)
      })
    state.checkpoint(Duration(10000))
    state.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreach(Blaher.blah))

    // Start the computation
    ssc.start()
    // Wait for the computation to terminate
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to spark-streaming documentation you should initialize context a bit differently:

```
// Function to create and setup a new StreamingContext
def functionToCreateContext(): StreamingContext = {
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(...)   // new context
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(...) // create DStreams
    ...
    ssc.checkpoint(checkpointDirectory)   // set checkpoint directory
    ssc
}

// Get StreamingContext from checkpoint data or create a new one
val context = StreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointDirectory, functionToCreateContext _)

// Do additional setup on context that needs to be done,
// irrespective of whether it is being started or restarted
context. ...

// Start the context
context.start()
context.awaitTermination()
```

see [checkpointing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing)

Answer (score 1):

As it is described in the [checkpointing documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing) you have to adjust your code to be able to restore state from the checkpoints.

In particular you cannot create `StreamingContext` directly but have to use [`StreamingContext.getOrCreate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext.html#getOrCreate%28java.lang.String,%20scala.Function0,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20boolean%29) method which takes:

- checkpoint directory
- function which can be used to set up the context (`Unit => StreamingContext`)

Comment: Thanks zero323.I was able to do it. It's remembering previous state now.